# Problem interfacing CR95HF with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I am interfacing a CR95HF with an Arduino to detect NFC tags. I have taken the code from [this link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/64903/nodemcu-cant-communicate-with-bm019-nfc-via-spi/71935?noredirect=1#comment156745_71935) as reference. I am able to get the response to the IDN command, and also set the protocol (ISO/IEC 14443-A). But the tag is not detected. What should I do to detect the tag?

Comment: is the tag functional?

Comment: yes tag is working ,I have tested with other nfc reader